# How to Display Google Map Iframe in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, iframe, webview

I've been trying to integrate a Google Map iframe into my React Native app, but I'm encountering issues. I've attempted to use the react-native-webview library, following the documentation, but it hasn't worked as expected. My goal is simply to display an office address on a Google Map within my app.

my code :-

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

    <WebView
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          source={{ html: '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3022" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>' }}
        />
```

I tried RenderHTML also but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Your code but give me error

```
Google Maps Platform rejected your request. Invalid request. Invalid 'pb' parameter.
```

so I tried my code it's look good

```
const MapScreen = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          source={{ html: `<html>
          <body>
            <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
      src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=The+Westin+Turtle+Bay+Resort+%26+Spa%2C+Mauritius&key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </body>
      </html>` }}
          style={styles.map}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
  
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    map: {
      flex: 1,
    },
  });
```

Hope this above code working fine

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! but i already try this ..! for me running in physical device works for me !

Comment: ok welcome  but I tried in my device it was give an error which i already mention above